# What is the meaning of the Rayleigh quotient of the laplacian?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, differential-operators

How should I read the Rayleigh quotient of something, in this case the laplacian operator of a variable? what does it mean the value of the Rayleigh quotient?

Comment: The [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Use_in_Sturm.E2.80.93Liouville_theory) requires the definition of an inner product. Here: of functions. It probably takes the form of an integral over a specified domain, using a product of functions as integrand. You need to find out what definition of inner product your text uses and on what functions it works on.

Comment: I have something like $\mathbf{Ray} (-\nabla \cdot \nabla, \nabla v)$ where $v$ is a velocity field. But I don't know what the Rayleigh quotient means...how should I read this value?

Comment: It's defined in the Wikipedia section I have linked to, in terms of an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. What's that inner product in your case? Encountered some integrals?

Comment: I know the mathematical expresion for the Rayleigh quotient, but I want to know what these integrals represent. The expresion I have is $\mathrm{Ray} (-\nabla \cdot \nabla, \nabla v) = \frac{- \int_{\Omega_\delta} -\nabla \cdot \nabla (\nabla v) :\nabla v\, dA}{\int_{\Omega_\delta} \nabla v:\nabla v\,dA}$...but what does the quotient mean? Something like a physical interpretation?

Comment: If you move that comment into the question, it might attract answers.

Comment: You'd probably also want to describe the boundary conditions on $\partial\Omega_\delta$ and whether $v$ is curl-free and/or div-free, for a remote chance of getting a physical interpretation.

Comment: ... and how the double-contraction operator is defined, e.g. $(\nabla v):(\nabla v) = \operatorname{tr}\bigl((\nabla v)^\top\cdot(\nabla v)\bigr)$ or without the transposition? Such things matter for interpretation.